# How to get a more specific type from "object type" in flow?

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

Well consider the following code:

```
class base<T: {[string]: any}> {
    field: T;
}

type SpecificTy = {|
    val: number,
    field: string,
|}

class subclass<T = SpecificTy> extends base<T> {}
```

This gives the following error:

```
`T` [1] is incompatible with object type [2] in type argument `T`. [incompatible-type-arg]
```

How would I create a type that is "object with just attributes x,y and z" to provide to a base class that accepts "any object"?

Comment: Are you sure you want classes? It kind of looks like you just want object types. Are you planning on using the `new` keyword here?

Comment: @LyleUnderwood yes but that's now removed for brevity. The actual use case is a class that *has an* object type, where the object type is a template parameter to the class.

Comment: Ah, I think I read it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you make your object types read-only:

```js
class base<T: { +[string]: any }> {
    field: T;
}

type SpecificTy = $ReadOnly<{|
    val: number,
    field: string,
|}>;

class subclass<T: SpecificTy> extends base<T> {}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBGkFMA8AVAXNA3tA1AbQgBcAnASwDsBzAXQzHIE9oBfAPiwChpvoAzUhCAAmGFAG4OzDh0IMADgmgBlBcFL9gKJgF5oAEgBKCMEIDy5EAySYAPlx4A3MCAzkArgFtYCYgBp73PyCItBEZFT+NmwSHKCQMBBusHFQqBgqCGoaWuwIAB6ECORCMPAQyCjsmMxAA)

Or if you don't include the index type:

```js
class base<T: {}> {
    field: T;
}

type SpecificTy = {|
    val: number,
    field: string,
|};

class subclass<T: SpecificTy> extends base<T> {}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBGkFMA8AVAXNA3gXwHxYChpjoAzASwRABMMUBuA7AggFwE8AHBaAZW+DkKwFO2gBeLAB8iJAG5gQGAHYBXALawEAJwA0s4hSq1oEVtvLKA5vqnZGBUJBgRVsJ1FQZ+CQcNH4CAAerAjK1DDwEMgo+DhAA)